# Why must we follow the formula of potential $V$ if we want to calculate the charge, instead of following the formula of electric field

Tags: electric-fields, charge, potential

> There are two spherical conductor A and B,and their radius are $r_a$ and $r_b $, and their charge are $q_1$ and $q_2$, and $q_1+q_2=Q$.

> Now they are connected with each other with a wire, assume the distance  $d$ between them is longer than $r_a$ and $r_b$, so their charge is Uniform distribution, the figure is as below

> [image: Charge diagram]

> Now find the charge of A and B.

$V=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0R}=constant$, so $Q_A=Q \times \frac{r_a}{r_a+r_b}$ and $Q_B=Q \times \frac{r_b}{r_a+r_b}$

---

I have a question about this solution, if I can say because the formula of potential $V=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0R}$,so the  $Q_A=Q \times \frac{r_a}{r_a+r_b}$,

why can't I say because the electric field $E=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0R^2}=constant$, so the $Q_A=Q \times \frac{r_a ^2}{r_a^2+r_b^2}$?

#### Question:

Why must we follow the formula of potential $V$ if we want to calculate the charge, instead of following the formula of electric field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it's true $E$ should be constant on the surface of one sphere, it won't necessarily be equal to $E$ at the surface of the other sphere.  There's no reason for this, and in fact you've just shown that they cannot be equal if $r_a\neq r_b$. There *is* a physical reason for the value $V$ to be equal on both spheres, which is the charge will distribute itself form high $V$ to low $V$ until the $V$s are the same.

Comment: i don't understand your explanation totally,but after reading your  explanation,i have a new thinking of this,the relation of $Q$ and $V$ is current $I$,and the $I$ will flow from high $V$ to low $V$ by the wire until the $V$ are the same,that is why we use the formula of $V$ instead of $E$,does this explanation make sense?or is this that you want to tell me?

Comment: Yes.  Differences in $V$ are what drive things to move (things falling from high places to low places, or charge moving from high potential to low potential).  They will stop moving when the potentials are equal, because there's no longer a driving force.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is that $|\vec{E}|$ is *not*, in general, constant over the surface of a conductor;  this only happens for a spherical conductor.  When you attach the two spheres, they form one big non-spherical conductor, and so we shouldn't expect $|\vec{E}|$ to be constant over its surface.

Answer (score 1):

The potential on the surface of the conductor is the potential energy that an electron has if it's on that surface (or more precisely $q_eV$, the charge of the electron times the voltage of the conductor it sits on). So if the potential on the surface of sphere A is $V_A$ and there is a more positive potential $V_B$ on the surface of sphere B, the electron will move from sphere A to sphere B (and energy will be released in the form of heat as it does this movement). But the electrons moving from sphere A to sphere B will make the potential on sphere B more negative. Until the potentials are equal, and electrons no longer want to move from one sphere to the other.

So this is why the potentials are equal - potential tells you "where charged particles want to move". And in a conductor, the charged particles will move until every connected (or "shorted") charged surface has the same potential.

There is simply no reason to think the electric field on the surface of the conductors should be equal.

But also, I think the answer is wrong - or rather you've made an approximation you weren't supposed to make. Only because the length $d$ is totally left out of the answer. If the sphere's are really far away, it's fair to approximate that the two sphere's potential doesn't affect eachother. If they're an intermediate distance apart, you still can ignore the effect of the charge distribution being nonuniform, but you do need to account for the effect of sphere A's potential on sphere B.  So the potential on sphere B should be
$$
V_b=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\left(\frac{Q_b}{r_b}+\frac{Q_a}{d+r_a}\right)
$$

Comment: i don't understand your explanation totally too,but after reading your  explanation,i have a new thinking of this,the relation of $Q$ and $V$ is current $I$,and the $I$ will flow from high $V$ to low $V$ by the wire until the $V$ are the same,that is why we use the formula of $V$ instead of $E$,does this explanation make sense?or is this that you want to tell me?

Comment: the reason i think of the formula of $E$ is because there is also $Q$ in the formula of $E$

Comment: If the "wire" has resistance $R$, then the current along the wire from sphere A to sphere B will be $(V_A-V_B)/R$ - if that's negative it implies the current goes the other way. Sure that's a fine way of looking at it. But I was trying to invoke a more general concept - the potential tells you "where the charge wants to be". The electric field tells you "which way the charge is being pushed at that point." And since E is the gradient of V, if V is constant along the conductor, E=0, and charges aren't being pushed anywhere too.